# How to restrict kotlin from using java api which is announced above jdk1.6

Tags: kotlin, gradle-plugin

My compilation environment is jdk1.8 and runtime environment is jdk1.6. `java` plugin of gradle has `sourceCompatibility` attribute. It is valid for java project.
For example: when `sourceCompatibility=1.6`, compiler will report error if I use the api such as `Paths` which is from jdk1.7.

but `sourceCompatibility` attribute doesn't work for kotlin project. I understand it is out of `java` plugin's scope. But I am strange whether `kotlin` plugin of gradle hasn't similar attribute. (`jvmTarget` attribute is 1.6 by default, it does't prevent me from using jdk1.7 api)

=== my code ===

kotlin code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val pp = Paths.get("/tmp")
    ... ...
}
```

I want kotlin's compiler to report errors, but the compilation is successful,

parent `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
    }
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
    compileJava.sourceCompatibility=1.6
    compileJava.targetCompatibility=1.6
    compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    // For ubuntu
    compileJava.options.bootClasspath = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar'
}
```

child kotlin project `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

mainClassName = 'net.cat.ApplictionKt'
version='1.0'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'xxxx',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.0"
    ... ... 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `jdkHome` property of the Kotlin compiler:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jdkHome = '[path to 1.6 JDK]'
    }
}
```